# jqgrid edit mode - not setting data when the focus is not changed inside the jqgrid itself

Tags: jqgrid

I have a weird problem while editing jqgrid cell.

- I got a Save button to grab changed cell value from grid and post it to server for saving.
- When I edit the cell and move the focus anywhere else on the grid table, and click on the Save button, the cell value is passed correctly.
- But if I edit the cell and click on the save button directly without changing focus inside the grid table, it is loosing its changed data.
- I am using $("#vehicleListTable").getChangedCells('all'); to get all edited rows from the grid.

I tried to capture events "beforeSubmitCell, afterEditCell ,   beforeSaveCell,   afterSaveCell,   afterSaveCell "  to see whether its getting called when I finish editing cell and moving focus to Save button, and found none of this is getting invoked. They are getting invoked when I change the cell and move the focus inside the grid itself.

Can any one help me out?
following is the snippet of how I create the jggrid table.

```
function initTable() {
            var vehTypesStr = "all:All;C:Car or Light Commercial;T:Heavy Commercial;M:Motorcycle;B:Boat;H:Caravan;R:Relocatable;A:Trailer";
            var stockTypesStr = "all:All;N:New;U:Used";
            var priceStatusTypesStr = "all:All;1:Over priced;-1:Under Priced;0:Neutral priced";
            jQuery("#vehicleListTable").jqGrid({                    
                url:'fetch-vehicle-list-json.action?q=2', 
                datatype: "json", 
                colNames:[                      
                    'Exception',
                    'Stock Number',
                    'Stock Type',
                    'Vehicle Type',
                    'Make',
                    'Model',
                    'Year',
                    'Drive Away Price',
                    'Price (unqualified)',
                    'Body Style',
                    'Exterior Base Colour',
                    'Odometer',
                    'Image Count',
                    'Price Status',
                    'Edited Online',
                    'Added Online'], 
                colModel:[  
                    {name:'exception',index:'exception',width:55,sortable:false,formatter:exceptionImagesFormatter,search:false},
                    {name:'stockNum',index:'stockNum',width:90},
                    {name:'vehicleNewUsedType',index:'vehicleNewUsedType',width:70,stype: 'select',searchoptions:{ sopt:['eq'], value: stockTypesStr}},
                    {name:'vehicleType',index:'vehicleType',width:120,stype: 'select',searchoptions:{ sopt:['eq'], value: vehTypesStr}},
                    {name:'make',index:'make',width:90},
                    {name:'model',index:'model',width:90},
                    {name:'year',index:'year',width:60,align:"right",search:false},
                    {name:'driveAwayPrice',index:'driveAwayPrice',width:90,align:'right',formatter:'currency',formatoptions:{thousandsSeparator:',',decimalPlaces:2,prefix:'$ ',defaulValue:''},search:false,editable:false,editrules:{number:true}},
                    {name:'egcPrice',index:'egcPrice',width:90,align:"right",formatter:'currency',formatoptions:{thousandsSeparator:",",decimalPlaces:2,prefix:"$ ",defaulValue:""},search:false},
                    {name:'bodyStyle',index:'bodyStyle',width:70},
                    {name:'exteriorColour',index:'exteriorColour',width:100,editable:false},
                    {name:'odometer',index:'odometer',width:70,search:false},
                    {name:'photoCount',index:'photoCount',width:80,align:"right",search:false},
                    {name:'priceStatus',index:'priceStatus',width:80,formatter:priceStatusImagesFormatter,stype: 'select',searchoptions:{ sopt:['eq'], value: priceStatusTypesStr }},
                    {name:'editedOnline',index:'lastModified',width:80,search:false,hidden:true},
                    {name:'addedOnline',index:'created',width:80,search:false,hidden:true}
                ],
                rowNum:20,
                scroll:1, 
                gridview: true,
                pager: '#vehicleListPager',
                sortname: "<s:property value="vehicleSearch.sortByField"/>",
                <s:if test="vehicleSearch.sortAscending">
                    sortorder:"asc",
                </s:if>
                <s:if test="!vehicleSearch.sortAscending">
                    sortorder:"desc",
                </s:if>
                viewrecords: true,
                recreateForm: true,
                recreateFilter: true,
                caption:"<s:property value="dealer.name"/>",
                multiselect: true,
                width: "40%",
                height: "250",                                      
                onSelectRow: handleTableOnSelect,                 
                beforeSelectRow: handleTableBeforeSelectRow,
                //afterInsertRow: handleTableAfterInsertRow,   
                onSelectAll: handleTableOnSelectAll,   
                loadComplete: handleTableLoadComplete,
                beforeSubmitCell: getEdittedCellData,
                afterEditCell  : getEdittedCellData,
                beforeSaveCell : getEdittedCellData,
                afterSaveCell  : getEdittedCellData,
                afterSaveCell  : getEdittedCellData       
            });
        }
```

Thanks
Sudha

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem - the cell is still in edit mode and the GetChangedCells method won't get the value because it hasn't been "saved" by the grid.  To do that, follow these steps -

Declare two variables to store the current row and column for the cell that is being edited.

```
var saverow;
var savecol;
```

Use the afterEditCell cell edit event to store the current row and column into your new variables.  This is done in the jqGrid initialization options.

```
afterEditCell: function (id, name, val, IRow, ICol) {
     saverow = IRow;
     savecol = ICol;
}
```

In your Save button's click handler, determine if you have a cell in edit mode and then call the saveCell method on the jqGrid.  Pass in the cell's row and column values.  This will store the value.
Also call the editCell method on the jqGrid, passing in the cell's row and column values AND a value of false.  This will take the cell out of edit mode.  Reset your row and column values to a null value.

```
// if a cell is currently in edit mode, then we need to save it and exit edit mode
if (saverow != null && savecol != null) {
    $("#vehicleListTable").jqGrid('saveCell', saverow, savecol, true);
    $("#vehicleListTable").jqGrid('editCell', saverow, savecol, false);
    saverow = null;
    savecol = null;
}
```